# What am I doing wrong with my controller to load images?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to be able to pull images from a folder and put them in a carousel. So far I have the following in my angular controller.

```
var carousel = angular.module('revampApp', []);

carousel.controller('carouselController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('../Images/carousel/').success(function(images){
        //Images
        $scope.images = images;
    })
});
```

And in my html body I have this:

```
<div class="img-carousel carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" ng-Controller="carouselController">
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="image in images">
              <img alt="First slide" data-ng-src="{{image.images}}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href=".img-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href=".img-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
    </div>
```

However, I keep getting an error in the console that says "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/ng/areq?p0=CarouselController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined" But I can't figure out what it is I am doing wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you set your ng-app correctly ?

Comment: I believe so. I have this at the top of my HTML: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="revampApp">`

Comment: Maybe not an issue, but note that at the error you get `CarouselController`, while your controller is `carouselController` (lower `c` for the 1st letter).

Comment: Just checked my file system. I had the class named CarouselController. Also I just noticed I didn't import my js file. So there's that... Now I have to figure out why it isn't seeing the directory

Comment: When you go to ../Images/carousel/ by typing the URL in your browser address bar, does it display a JSON array?

Comment: Not a json array. It displays a directory where the images are stored. I probably have to specify something that I am missing. If you can't tell I am still new to angular.

Comment: Angular will happily get JSON from an HTTP response body and parse it to a JavaScript array, but it won't magically parse an HTML page containing a listing of images into a JavaScript array. You need a REST service returning images as JSON.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, I will just put in a JSON file for now then. This is just a general mockup site so I am learning. You wouldn't happen to have a tutorial on a REST service would you?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to write it: Java, Ruby, NodeJS, C#... And once you've chosen your serer-side language, you'll also have to choose which framework/libraries you want to use.